# How to make addin to remember width of custom task pane word 2010 using VSTO (Visual Studio 2013/C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsto

How to make addin to remember width of custom task pane word 2010 using VSTO (Visual Studio 2013/C#)?

I have created a Word 2010 Addin using VS 2013 with custom task pane in addin but there are no event I fond, where we can keep the width of custom task pane (in config or db) so that It can be loaded with that default width next time when we open word.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [document before close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834271(v=office.15).aspx) event to store the width?

Comment: I appreciate for quick response this could be a one of the way to handle this, but my concern is if user open multiple instance without closing one of them, than also it should be applicable for all instances, anyway for now I got the solution :) thanks again

Comment: I'm glad you managed to work it out. Maybe you could share your solution so others with the same problem can use it?